# Storing information in MYSQL DB with PHP OOP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have the below code all indications show it is working I get the "Sucess" message and the echos within the storeData() function are showing the correct information. HOWEVER the data is not being store in the MySQL database, nothing is happening.  Can anyone see why?

I added the `echo`s just to check it was reading the right $this values and it is.

```
 if ($result = $stmt->execute())
                      {
                          echo "Success";
                          echo $this->domainname;
                          echo $this->date;
                      }
```

Full Code -

```
<?php
class domain
{
    protected $domainname;
    protected $whois;
    protected $dnsa;
    protected $dnsmx;
    protected $dnstxt;
    protected $dnsns;
    protected $blacklist;
    protected $ping;
    protected $tracert;
    protected $nmap;
    protected $ip;
    protected $date;

    private $servername = "localhost";
    private $username = "";
    private $password = "";
    private $dbname = "domainhistory";

    function __construct($domain)
      {
          echo $domain."Passed";
          $this->date = $date1 = date("Y/m/d");
          $this->domainname = $domain;
          $this->ip = gethostbyname("$domain");
          $this->whois = shell_exec("whois $domain | tr -d '\'\' ");
          $this->ssl = shell_exec("curl --insecure -v https://$domain 2>&1 | awk 'BEGIN { cert=0 } /^\* SSL connection/ { cert=1 } /^\*/ { if (cert) print }' | grep -v subject");
          $this->dnsa = shell_exec("dig $domain A | grep A | grep -v ns | grep $domain | grep -v ';' ");
          $this->dnsmx = shell_exec("dig $domain MX | grep MX | grep -v ns| grep $domain | grep -v ';' ");
          $this->dnstxt = shell_exec("dig $domain TXT | grep TXT | grep -v ns | grep $domain | grep -v ';' ");
          $this->dnsns = shell_exec("dig $domain NS | grep NS | grep -v A |  grep $domain | grep -v ';' ");
          $this->blacklist = shell_exec("curl -I -X GET api.moocher.io/badip/$ip | grep HTTP");
          $this->ping = shell_exec("ping -c 3 $domain");
          $this->tracert = shell_exec("traceroute -m 10 $domain");
          $this->nmap = shell_exec("nmap -n $domain");
      }
####This called when you request a value
      function __get($name)
        {
          ##Checks if the value is empty or not before returning.
          return $this->$name;
        }

### Function to store the object inside of the MYSQL Database
      function storeData()
      {
            $servername = $this->servername;
            $username = $this->username;
            $password = $this->password;
            $dbname = $this->dbname;
            #Opens the MYSQL Connection
            $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
                if (!$conn)
              {
                die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
              }
      #Prepares the mySQL statement, (stops SQL injection)
      $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `history` (`domain`, `date`, `whois`, `dnsa`, `dnsmx`, `dnstxt`, `dnsns`, `blacklist`, `ping`, `tracert`, `nmap`, `sslinfo`)
      VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
      $stmt->bind_param('ssssssssssss', $this->domainame, $this->date, $this->whois, $this->dnsa, $this->dnsmx, $this->dnstxt, $this->dnsns, $this->blacklist, $this->ping, $this->tracert, $this->nmap, $this->sslinfo);
                  #Executes the prepared statement
                  if ($result = $stmt->execute())
                      {
                          echo "Success";
                          echo $this->domainname;
                          echo $this->date;
                      }
           #closes the mysql connection
            mysqli_close($conn);
      }
}
 ?>
```

#### Update

I got it all working as expected (issue was `$this->sslinfo` when it is `$this->ssl`, also spelled `$this->domainname` wrong).

I am still getting a strange error in error_logs:

> mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning: Wrong parameter count for mysqli_stmt::bind_param() i -

However, its not the wrong parameter count - I have a column in MySQL which is a unique ID so may be to do with that.

Comment: `return $this->$name;` - `name` shouldn't have a dollar sign.

Comment: this is OOP related also and the related tag was removed in an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44484216/2), which I don't know why.

Comment: If you are referring to the  function __get($name)    If i take out the $ on the return the whole thing stops working.  The $name refers to a variable passed to the get method.

Comment: check for errors then, on both the php and mysql side.

Comment: Check your mysql working  by inserting static values in the table.

Comment: Got it all working as excpected (issue was $this->sslinfo  when it is $this->ssl, also spelt $this->domainname wrong)     ..still getting a strange error in error_logs -  mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  Wrong parameter count for mysqli_stmt::bind_param() i   - However, its not wrong parameter count I have a collum in mysql which a unique ID so may be to do with that.  (Tho i have no idea what the 'ssssss" is for, I just know if i take it out, it breaks.

Comment: The 'sssss...' bit is defining the types of parameters your passing, 's' means they are all strings.

Comment: Ah right, I have no idea why its saying wrong paremeter count, I have 12 ?, and 12 variables being inserted. Only thing it could is because mysql tabe actually has 13 collums? But I dont want to insert into the ID collum.

Comment: @TheOne745665 does the warning still appear?